# How can obtain age by birth date

Tags: php

I want get the exact age of the following date in var `$birth_date` by php, How is it?

`$birth_date = 2011/12/16;`

$birth_date => For example, this is my birth date.

For example output from my birth date is: `0 Year, 0 Month, 1 Day`

Comment: please use the search function. this has been asked before multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using unix timestamps to handle birthdates is a bad idea, as their range is only very limited (1970-2038). Use php's builtin `DateTime` class instead:

```
$then = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y/m/d", "2011/12/16");
$diff = $then->diff(new DateTime());
echo $diff->format("%y year %m month %d day\n");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

  //calculate years of age (input string: YYYY-MM-DD)
  function birthday ($birthday, $separator){
    list($year,$month,$day) = explode($separator, $birthday);
    $year_diff  = date("Y") - $year;
    $month_diff = date("m") - $month;
    $day_diff   = date("d") - $day;
    if ($day_diff < 0 || $month_diff < 0)
      $year_diff--;
    return $year_diff;
  }
  echo getAge('2010/12/16', '/');
?>
```

Reformatted from http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1310

I also recommend the [Tizag PHP tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/).

Comment: Please, read again my post. I want get age from this date: `2011/12/16`

Comment: If you replace "-" with "/" it should work.

Comment: @KateWintz, seriously, couldn't you even spend 2 seconds looking at the code to figure out you need to change `explode("-",$birthday);` to `explode("/",$birthday);` to make it work for your format? Please, at least try and learn from the answers provided instead of thinking StackOverflow is your own personal coding machine.

Comment: See here, don't work: http://codepad.viper-7.com/S1nKT3

Comment: You do realise you have to call a function for it to work? http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZrBYCE

Comment: ok, if Year was 2011 return is 0, how can obtain exact age in Year, Month, Day, for example in above birth date return should was this: `0 Year, 0 Month, 1 Day`. how can fix it?